# How can I animate multiple points to revolve independently around a single point?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am attempting to build a scatterplot and am stumped on the animations. Ultimately, I want there to be >1000 points, plotted at a random, normal distribution around (0,0). Each point should then rotate either clockwise or counter-clockwise around (0,0) at varying speeds.

I was trying to do this with a loop function that would randomize movement, but it is extremely slow, and as of yet I have been unable to make more than one point move:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 4,3
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from math import sqrt, exp
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set the axes limits
ax.axis([-2.5,2.5,-2.5,2.5])
# set equal aspect such that the circle is not shown as ellipse
ax.set_aspect("equal")
# create a point in the axes

for i in range(0,6):
    x = np.random.normal()
    y = np.random.normal()
    r = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
    def circle(phi):
        return np.array([r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)])
    point, = ax.plot(x,y, marker="o")
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=10, blit=True, repeat=True,
                    frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False))
    
plt.show()

writer = PillowWriter(fps=25) 
ani.save(r'[path --> .gif]', writer=writer)
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: your `update` is missing - do you have this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. I find updates very confusing (probably why my code isn't working!) How would I phrase that within the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 4,3
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from math import sqrt, exp


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set the axes limits
ax.axis([-2.5,2.5,-2.5,2.5])
# set equal aspect such that the circle is not shown as ellipse
ax.set_aspect("equal")
# create a point in the axes

def update(i):
    x = np.random.normal()
    y = np.random.normal()
    r = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
    def circle(phi):
        return np.array([r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)])
    ax.plot(x,y, marker="o")

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, func=update, interval=10, blit=False, repeat=True,
                frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Not quite, but your code did help me learn to populate the markers one by one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite figure out how to update your code to get towards the solution.  But I came up with this, which uses some of the same logic:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# how many points to draw
points = 100

# generating x & y coordinates, their distance from origin,
# their angle relative to the origin, and random rotations to
# apply to each point each frame
xs = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, points)
ys = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, points)
ls = np.sqrt(xs**2 + ys**2)
angles = np.arctan2(ys, xs)
negs = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=points)
rotations = (np.random.uniform(np.pi/50, np.pi/6, size=points) * negs)

# initialize a figure, make a color range to color each point
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
ax.set_xlim(-1.5,1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5,1.5)
color_divisions = [(1/points)*i for i in range(points)]
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('jet')
colors = cmap(color_divisions)

# update function
# update gets fed elements from the frames parameter of FuncAnimation
# each update we clear the graph (but reapply the same x/y limits)
# we then draw the points as a scatter and update the data for the next frame
# add each rotation to each angle, and then calculate the new x and y coordinates
# with numpy these calculations can be done w/o a loop, but global is needed
# to update variables from the global scope
def update(f):
    global xs, ys, angles, rotations
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-1.5,1.5)
    ax.set_ylim(-1.5,1.5)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, color=colors)
    angles += rotations
    ys = np.sin(angles) * ls
    xs = np.cos(angles) * ls

#call the animation and save
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=200, frames=range(100))
ani.save('ani.gif', writer='pillow')
```

Producing the following animation of 100 points rotating around the origin at random speeds:

[image]

You can increase the number of points (this may get pretty slow for 1000 points), tweak the FPS (`interval`), or the amount to rotate each point by.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Only question I'd add is this: Is it possible to save this ani as a gif with a transparent background? (In my case, so it could be inserted into a Powerpoint to lay over a background image)?

Comment: @stimsssss Hmmmm I am not aware of how to do this. I have seen [this post](https://adrian.pw/blog/matplotlib-transparent-animation/) and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406617/mplot3d-animation-with-transparent-background) which you could look into. I wasn't able to quickly get it working for this example. But if you can't get something going, you can open a new post (showing what didn't work)

Comment: Will do @Tom thanks. I will keep working, and if I find a successful answer, then I will post it here for future reference.